# Objective-C – How to hide methods for a class that implements a protocol

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Question is in title. Code example:

```
UIViewController <MyProtocol> *viewcontroller = ...;

[viewcontroller methodFromProtocol]; // I expect to be able to call all methods that the protocol defines

//UIViewControllerSubclass implements MyProtocol

UIViewControllerSubclass *viewControllerSubclassWithoutMyProtocol = [[UIViewControllerSubclass alloc] init];
[viewControllerSubclassWithoutMyProtocol methodThatIsNotInTheInterfaceIsDisplayedHere]; // I only expect to be able to call the methods that are defined in this class' interface even though this class implements MyProtocol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, but I think you are asking if you can "privately" conform to a protocol?

This can be done by declaring that you conform to the protocol inside the implementation file, rather than the interface file. With view controllers, you can do this in the class continuation that is generated for you automatically in the .m file, otherwise you'll need to add the class continuation in yourself:

```
@interface MyVCSubclass () <MyProtocol>
```

Now, any class that imports only the header file will not know your controller conforms to the protocol.

Comment: Thanks that seems to do "part" of the job :) Now if I only want some of these methdos that the protocol defines to ONLY be internally accessed from the class that implements the protocol and not visible outside the class. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Define "visible"? And see Amy Worral's excellent answer for info on why this sort of thing isn't often done. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Visible in the meaning that Xcode will not show auto-completion for the protocol methods if I try to access the class without the "<MyProtocol>". What I'm trying to achieve is to have some classes implement protocol methods that I want all my classes to implement at a bare minimum. Then some of these methods that these classes implement are ONLY to be called from the class itself. So in other words, I want to achieve the same thing as when you declare the "public" methods in the interface and then in the implementation you declare the methods that are only to be used inside this class.

Comment: You'd probably have to split it into two protocols. I'm not sure if it's worth it trying to fight the autocomplete, it may be too "helpful".

Answer (score 2):

> `[viewControllerSubclassWithoutMyProtocol methodThatIsNotInTheInterfaceIsDisplayedHere];`
>
> I only expect to be able to call the methods that are defined in this class' interface even though this class implements MyProtocol

That's a bad expectation. Objective-C lets you call any method that an object implements. If you try to call a method that an object doesn't implement, two things should happen:

- You get a compiler warning (not an error though)
- When the code runs, it crashes, unless you've taken steps to handle such an event.

If a class implements a protocol but doesn't declare that it does so in a public header, then you can still call the method (since Objective C doesn't have private methods). I'd have thought you'd get a compiler warning, but if you're calling this from a file within the same Xcode project as your object (that is, you're not building a static library) then it's possible that Xcode is getting smart and deciding that since the method exists, it must be OK to call.

It wasn't clear from your question what you expected to happen and what actually happened. If you supply that information, we'll be able to give better answers.

Comment: I was expecting Xcode to not show up `methodThatIsNotInTheInterfaceIsDisplayedHere` in the auto-completion.